# How can I convert an object layer to an ordinary layer in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

How can I convert an object layer to an ordinary layer in Illustrator?

In the illustration below ... how do I drag the Path object, which is the sun, from its layer to a new separated layer?

Of course I can do it by making a new layer and copy and paste in place. However, in my case this process will be a headache. Besides that, I want to preserve the layer properties like color and name and the value of opacity. What I need is just to select the layer and drag it outside its' main layer to be a new layer by itself.

[image]

Comment: I would say drag it out of the layer, but I guessing you've tried that. Can you provide an example/image?

Comment: please check mu updated question. Sure dragging a layer from its group outside it is simple and dragging a sublayer from its parent layer to another layer also is simple. what I am asking for is how to drag the sublayer with all its property to be an independent layer. I don't want to make a new Layer each time what to do that and copy and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highlight the object or objects and choose "Collect In New Layer" from the **Layer Panel Menu**

The Layers Panel is *actually* a Layers, Sublayers and Object panel. Anything with brackets in its name (`<Path>, <Group>`) is an **object** and not a layer.

Layers can contain sublayers and objects.

Sublayers can contain objects.

Objects can only contain other objects.

What you are asking is how to turn an object into a layer by dragging.

**You can't just drag an object out of a layer to create a new layer.** You have to either create the layer first, then drag the object to the new layer, or use the menu command I've indicated above to generate a layer containing the object(s).